# How to Capitalise first letter of directory

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to get all directories in the URI to be in lowercase if a user types the URI in upper case. Such as `https://example.com/hOmE` instead of `https://example.com/home`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451171/rewrite-uppercase-url-to-lowercase-url-htaccess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you'd have to do that in your htaccess file. You can manipulate the URL there using regex. Just google

> htaccess regex capitalize

to get started